# How to read barcode from handheld barcode scanner using zxing in Java

Tags: java, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

I am using the open source Java library called ‘**zxing**’ (Zebra Crossing) In java. My code is here

```
package eg.com.taman.bc.tut;

import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder.ErrorCorrectionLevel;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder.Mode;
import eg.com.tm.barcode.processor.BarcodeEngine;
import eg.com.tm.barcode.processor.config.DecodeConfig;
import eg.com.tm.barcode.processor.config.EncodeConfig;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;


public class BarcodeApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // File will be used for creating the QRCode barcode type.
      File qrCodeFile = new File("C:\\barcode\\QRCode.png");


      // Building the encoding configurations - using builder battern
      EncodeConfig encodeConfig =
              new EncodeConfig.Builder().createDirectories(Boolean.TRUE)
              .isQRCodeFormat(Boolean.TRUE)
              .withErrorCorrLevel(ErrorCorrectionLevel.M).build();

      // Generating the QRCode barcode

      String content = "This is the contents of the barcode. 7654321 (QRCode)";

      BarcodeEngine.encode(qrCodeFile, content, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200, 200, encodeConfig);

      encodeConfig =
              new EncodeConfig.Builder().createDirectories(Boolean.TRUE).
              withCharactersMode(Mode.ALPHANUMERIC).build();




      System.out.println("------------------- Begins Writing barcodes -------------------\n");
      System.out.println("Is QRCode Created? " + (qrCodeFile.exists() ? "Yes " : "Not not ") + "Created");
      System.out.println("\n------------------- Finished Writing barcodes -------------------");

      // Now we are going to decode (read) back contents of created barcodes

      // Building the decoding configurations - using builder battern
      DecodeConfig decodeConfig =
              new DecodeConfig.Builder()
              .withHumanBarcodes(Boolean.TRUE)
              .build();


      Map<BarcodeEngine.DecodeResults, Object> results = BarcodeEngine.decode(qrCodeFile, decodeConfig);

      String decodeText = (String) results.get(BarcodeEngine.DecodeResults.RESULT);
      String barcodeType = ((BarcodeFormat) results.get(BarcodeEngine.DecodeResults.BARCODE_FORMATE)).name();

      System.out.println("\n------------------- Begins reading barcodes -------------------\n");
      System.out.println("The decoded contents is: \"" + decodeText + "\", Barcode type is: " + barcodeType);



      System.out.println("The decoded contents is: \"" + decodeText + "\", Barcode type is: " + barcodeType);

      System.out.println("\n------------------- Finished reading barcodes -------------------");
      System.out.println("decode Text : "+decodeText);
      System.out.println("barcode Type : "+barcodeType);
   }
}
```

**The code reads a Qr barcode as image file. Now i want to use the handheld barcode scanner to read the barcode. Any help ?????**

I am working in java desktop application Not Android.

Comment: I have attached my code , so if anything is unclear please inform me.

Comment: So the question is "how is the handheld barcode scanner used to read the barcode?" Is that it?

Comment: Can you please explain how the code you have posted is relevant to the Question?  It looks to me like it is nothing to do with reading QR codes using a scanner.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are looking for a scanner that support HID mode.

Your options are a [Bluetooth scanner with HID mode](https://www.google.com/search?q=bluetooth+hid+barcode+scanner&oq=bluetooth+hid+barcode+scanner&aqs=chrome..69i57.4638j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) or a USB scanner (most act like keyboards).

Once you've picked one, HID mode is basically the same on all scanners and you can find many questions on Stackoverflow about capturing scanner input and separating it from user input on a normal keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that zxing is for generating and processing QR code *images* ... as you are doing in your code.  It is not an API for driving a barcode scanner.  If you want one of those, you will need to say something about the device you are trying to use.

Comment: I don't know which device to buy , but i need one that will be like keyboard in programming.

Comment: Well until you've decided which one you are going to buy / use, we cannot advise you on how to program it.  You are going to need to research this for yourself.  Advice on selecting hardware is off topic.

Comment: Why is the device important? Given that the whole thing is about images, then all we need to know is the location of the generated image. If it does not write to the file system, then the image of known format has to be communicated in some other way. Can you cite one example device that illustrates the need-to-know of the device that is going to be used?

Comment: @eigenfield well we don't even know if the whole thing is about images, do we? a lot of barcode scanners are just acting as keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on it a little bit, and in most of cases it's working fine.
My code is:

```
    InputStream barCodeInputStream = new FileInputStream("test.png");
    BufferedImage barCodeBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(barCodeInputStream);
    LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(barCodeBufferedImage);
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
    Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
    Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
    System.out.println("Barcode text is " + result.getText());
```

This will work fine on QR as well as Barcode :)

Comment: and yes try in maven project so lib will automatically downloaded.